# Could you tell me what is wrong with this piece of code for my blog?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If I remove this code, my page loads. But If I add this, I get a HTTP Error 500 from my web matrix.

```
<?php
try {    
  if(isset(['submit'])) {
    include('config.php');
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $content = $_POST['editor1'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $tags = $_POST['tags'];
    $author = $_POST['author'];
    $thumbnail = $_POST['thumbnail'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO articles (Subject, Content, Date, Author, Tags, Thumbnail) VALUES ('$subject','$content','$date','$author','$tags', '$thumbnail')";
    $dbh->query($sql);   
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Read up on how to use [prepared statements](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) properly. As it stands, you're vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a statement:

```
if (isset(['submit']))
```

it should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

with all chance.

Anyway, you should bind parameters to the query, and not hardcode them into it.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. I can't believe that stupid mistake took so much of my time. -_-

Comment: @Sunny - find where your Apache logs are, they would have given you a line number at which the error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
if (isset(['submit']))
```

there is a variable missing. You may want to use this line:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

By the way your SQL code is open for blind SQL injections. You should parse the parameter or better still, use prepared statements.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO articles (Subject, Content, Date, Author, Tags, Thumbnail) VALUES (':subject',':content',':date',':author',':tags', ':thumbnail')");
$stmt->bindParam(':subject', $subject);
$stmt->bindParam(':content', $content);
// ...
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I wanted to ask if prepared statements are used only when inserting data into the database?

Comment: No you can use them for selects too. I would recomment you to use them for every kind of query with variables which come from the web.